# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN Azure web app

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I've just created a new website via azure's web app. I've done this several times before and never had a problem but now for some reason the site's DNS won't resolve!? Not even the custom domain but azure's own subdomain won't even resolve and the IP address 404's leading me to think this is an azure problem and nothing to do with my google DNS configuration for my custom domain I'm trying to setup. (golftipsters.com)

I even tried deleting and recreating the web app and app service. Got a new IP address but still the same problem. I deployed the site via continuous integration from bitbucket but even before that there should be some kind of placeholder?

https://www.golftipsters.azurewebsites.net/

http://20.40.202.16/

[image]
What's going on!?

It says my deployment is successful and active

[image]

Update:
After some trial an error creating new web apps. I've discovered that it's when I deploy my code via CI from bitbucket that this issue occurs. How could my code deployment cause the DNS to fail? Is it even the DNS then??

Comment: "What's going on!?" The name is not configured in the DNS hence it doesn't resolve. You can see it with a tool such as https://dnsviz.net/d/www.golftipsters.azurewebsites.net/YPj6gw/dnssec/  At this stage I don't think your question is on topic here as it is "just" a problem of DNS configuration for which you need to talk with your DNS provider.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Microsoft is the DNS provider, it's my understanding that this should be done automatically upon creating the resource. So I suppose my question is why hasn't it been done/how do I fix it in azure?

Comment: I just created another site the exact same way and it shows a placeholder as expected https://testfroggy.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: "Microsoft is the DNS provider," So did you start by asking them? They provide a service to you so they should be able to help you, no? "I just created another site the exact same way and it shows a placeholder as expected testfroggy.azurewebsites.net " No it is not the same. Your original name is 4 level deep, that one only 3. Are you sure Azure allows names with 4 labels? I don't know personnally, you should ask them or do a test with a similar name as your first name, so `www.testfroggy.azurewebsites.net` and not just `testfroggy.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: I asked them via their twitter and they linked me to this similar question that doesn't have a resolution https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/42f44235-9ff7-4fdf-bb13-c48d4f37ad72/this-site-can8217t-be-reached-issue-with-my-domain-pointing-to-azure-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview -  i tired all the suggestions in the thread and still nothing. I've now tried to deploy my site and linking my custom domain (golftipsters.com) via the test web app (testfroggy) and now that domain with the placeholder is showing the same thing!?

Comment: So, trying with a third instance. I created testapples.azurewebsites.net, the placeholder worked, then I deployed my site via CI from Bitbucket and now it's showing the DNS error. So somehow the deployment is causing this!?? What does dnsviz show you? http://testapples.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the problem was in the codebase I was trying to deploy. I had this code in the global.asax.cs that was trying to force www. and this was causing the DNS error.

```
        if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
        {
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
            Response.StatusCode = 301;
            Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```